# Динамическое изменение положения(процентов) элементов. Адаптивность

Tags: jquery, css

Такой случай. Начал работать над адаптивностью страницы. Пока что проблем куча. Сделал так: взял 4 элемента. Дал им ширину 25%. Пока что все ОК!

НО(!) когда меняю размер окна браузера они смещаются, пропадают. Но когда нажимаю "Обновить" все опять садится на свои места и все окей!

Вопрос(!), как сделать, чтобы все автоматически(динамично) подстраивалось. Т.е не нажимал "Обновить" чтобы опять все подсело на свои места, а при изменении ширины окна браузера динамически обновлялось и адаптировалось.

Заранее спасибо!

[image]
[image]

Comment: А при чем тут jQuery? Адаптивная верстка - это, в первую очередь, соответствующая разметка + правильно составленный css (в том числе и медиа-запросы). Вы скрываете от нас, как у вас там всё устроено, но если надо четыре элемента поставить в линию, то это можно и [таким образом сделать][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/YUNRx/

Comment: Вот скрины выложил. В первой фотке я просто изменил размер окна. А во втором после F5 все село на свои места

Comment: 25% от чего? у вас судя по всему контейнер имеет какое-то абсолютное значение для ширины, возможно, скриптом выставленное. и 25% берется от него.   
горизонтальный скроллинг на скринах намекает, что "адаптивность" сломалась еще раньше.  
размеры, заданные в процентах масштабируются при изменении размеров контейнера автоматически, видимо без вашего кода понять в чем ошибка будет понять сложно.

Comment: Вот: http://jsfiddle.net/msagN/

Comment: @navi1893 ну и? у вас только один блок (первый) имеет заданную ширину, остальные без ширины. а то, что у вас при обновлении срабатывает - вы же скриптом меняете ширину, которая устанавливается не в процентах, а в пикселях. 

    #bottom_menu_1 div {
      width:24.5%
    }

вот: http://jsfiddle.net/msagN/1/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй задать процентное соотношение не 25% а, н-р, 24.4%. Грубо, но все же..

Comment: а что это изменит? Я же ведь не это спрашиваю

Comment: да? а тогда что вы спрашиваете?